# How to use managed kubectl identity on Azure AKS to apply wildcard certificate

Tags: azure, kubernetes, dns, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

1. I registered a domain in google domain service, like:`mydomain.com`
2. create a DNS zone in Azure, like: `mydomain.com`, and go to google DNS service to change the DNS server as Azure provided.
3. create two azure managed identity: `myidentity` and `mykubeidentity`.
4. create a cluster `mycluster` with option: `--assign-identity <identity-id> --assign-kubelet-identity <kubelet-identity-id>`
5. create a public IP: `111.111.111.111`
6. add 4DNS A records:`mydomain.com`, `*.mydomain.com`, `mycluster` and `*.mycluster` in the DNS zone and point to the same IP.
7. using `ping mycluster.mydomain.com` to validate, and I can get the IP correctly.
8. use command `az aks show -n $CLUSTERNAME -g $CLUSTER_GROUP --query "identityProfile.kubeletidentity.objectId"` to get the principle ID of the kube-identity.
9. use command `az network dns zone show --name $ZONE_NAME --resource-group $ZONE_GROUP --query "id"` and the ID for the DNS zone
10. use command `az role assignment create --role "DNS Zone Contributor" --assignee $PRINCIPAL_ID --scope $ZONE_ID` to create role assignment.
11. use command `az identity show -n mykubeidentity -g myrg --query 'clientId'` to get the client ID value.
12. use command `kubectl create secret generic <secret_name> -n cert-manager --from-literal=<key>=<value>` to create a secret
13. create a cluster issuer with the following yaml values:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: mydomain.clusterissuer
spec:
  acme:
    email: abc@gmail.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: mydomain.clusterissuer
    server: "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
    solvers:
      -
        dns01:
          azureDNS:
            clientID: <get in the step 11>
            clientSecretSecretRef:
              key: <key>
              name: <secret_name>
            environment: AzurePublicCloud
            resourceGroupName: my-aks-rg
            hostedZoneName: mydomain.com
            subscriptionID: xxxx-xxx
            tenantID: xxxxxx-xxxxxx
```

14. use command `kubectl get clusterissuers` to check cluster issuers status:

```
NAME                         READY   AGE
mydomain.clusterissuer   True    19s
```

15. using command to apply wildcard certificate with the following yaml values:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: azure-wildcard-certificate
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  commonName: '*.mydomain.com'
  dnsNames:
    - '*.mycluster.mydomain.com'
    - 'mycluster.mydomain.com'
  secretName: azure-wildcard-certificate
  duration: 2160h
  renewBefore: 1h
  issuerRef:
    kind: ClusterIssuer
    name: mydomain.clusterissuer
```

16. use command 'kubectl get certificate -n kube-system` and always get this result:

```
NAME                                    READY   SECRET                                  AGE
azure-wildcard-certificate   False   azure-desheng-io-wildcard-certificate   37s
```

17. Follow this [link](https://cert-manager.io/docs/faq/acme/) to troubleshooting but no lucky. From the command `kubectl describe challenge`, I can see many error like:

```
cert-manager  Error presenting challenge: azure.BearerAuthorizer#WithAuthorization: Failed to refresh the Token for request to https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx-xxx/resourceGroups/my-aks-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/mydomain.com/TXT/_acme-challenge?api-version=2017-10-01: StatusCode=401 -- Original Error: adal: Refresh request failed. Status Code = '401'. Response body: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret provided. Ensure the secret being sent in the request is the client secret value, not the client secret ID, for a secret added to app '<the appid from step 11>'.\r\nTrace ID: xxxxxx\r\nCorrelation ID: xxxxxx\r\nTimestamp: 2022-02-08 03:27:51Z","error_codes":[7000215],"timestamp":"2022-02-08 03:27:51Z","trace_id":"xxxxxx","correlation_id":"xxxxx","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000215"} Endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/b9921086-ff77-4d0d-828a-cb3381f678e2/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0
```

It seems like cert-manager can't use the managed identity to handle authentication requirements from the Let's encrypt request.

BTW, I can't use the `Service Principle` approach in this account.

K8s version: `1.19.11`, but I can upgrade to `1.20` if needed.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak it's 1.19.11 now but I can upgrade to 1.20 if needed.

Comment: 1.20 is also unsupported. Could you update it to minimum 1.21?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak got a chance to test on 1.21.9 today but unfortunately this error message is the same. I guess the fundamental issue is: there is no client name associated with a managed identity.